# Dereferencing pointers in Go

Tags: pointers, go

I'm confused as to why line 15 is not valid. Why can't a pointer to a big.Int be dereferenced, whilst a pointer to an int can?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "big"
)

func main() {
    var c *int = getPtr()
    fmt.Println(c)
    fmt.Println(*c)

    var d *big.Int = big.NewInt(int64(0))
    fmt.Println(d)

    // does not compile - implicit assignment of big.Int
    // field 'neg' in function argument
    //fmt.Println(*d)
}

func getPtr() *int {
    var a int = 0
    var b *int = &a
    return b
}
```

Comment: The output is 
0x110480 (address of c)
0 (value of c)
0 (result of d.String() I assume)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because Int is a struct with unexported fields. When you pass a struct by value to a function, you're making a copy of it. The [Go spec](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html) states that for this to be legal

> ...either all fields of T must be
>   exported, or the assignment must be in
>   the same package in which T is
>   declared. In other words, a struct
>   value can be assigned to a struct
>   variable only if every field of the
>   struct may be legally assigned
>   individually by the program.